# What is wrong with this procedure to add 4 years to a date?

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I am trying to add 4 years to a string with a date format from South America. I tried the bellow code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$date_string = '10/10/2014';
$date = date_create($date_string);
$date_us_string = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
$date2_us = strtotime('+4 year', $date_us_string);
$date2_string = date_format($date2_us, 'd/m/Y');
```

But it isnt working and I dont know why. Anybody can help me?

Comment: What do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: I got Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, integer given, I was expecting a string with value 10/10/2018

Comment: So you should read the manual for date_format(). php.net search for date_format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP should be showing you an error. If not, you need to turn error reporting on. Here is the error:

> Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, null given

This is because that function only works with `DateTime()` objects. You are *not* using them throughout your code which is causing even more errors before you get this far. Here is working code that is simpler (and uses `DateTime()` throughout):

```
$date_string = '10/10/2014';
$date = new DateTime($date_string, new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));
$date->modify('+4 years');
echo $date->format('d/m/Y');
```

- [**Demo**](https://eval.in/306054)

Answer (score 0):

Just for curiosity, this also works:

```
$date_string = '30/10/2014';
$date_string = explode("/", $date_string);
$date_string = date('m/d/Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, $date_string[1], $date_string[0], $date_string[2]) );

function makeDate($date, $days, $mounths, $years){
    $date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date));
    $date = explode("/", $date);
    return date('d/m/Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, $date[1] + $mounths, $date[0] +  $days, $date[2] + $years) );
        }
        $dateadded = makeDate($date_string, 0, 0, 4);
        echo $dateadded;
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/306187)